# Calling script with the same @INC as the parent script

Tags: perl

I want to call an  external script with `system ($script)` or `do $script`. In my @INC i have some specific modules which I import. How can I call the `$script` and transfer it the same `@INC`?

Script1.pm

```
#importing some libs
#code
$script = "path_to_script";

system ($script);
```

Script2.pm

```
use LibFromScript1@INC;
```

And I get the Error :

> Can't locate LibFromScript1 in @INC...

Comment: The best solution to this would almost certainly be to rip all the functionality out of the second script, place it into a proper module, replace the second script with a lightweight wrapper around that module, and then use that module in Script1 instead of trying to shell out to run the other script.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you don't want to use the same **parameters** but the same **libs** or lib paths.

Comment: Yes, this is what I need

Comment: Then the title is a little bit misleading.

Comment: @dgw thank you, i updated the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to set the `PERL5LIB` environment variable. That will add a list of directories to the child process's `@INC` array

Your code would look something like

```
$ENV{PERL5LIB} = join ':', @INC;

system $script;
```

This has the disadvantage that the standard directories will also be added to `@INC`. It shouldn't cause any problems, but it would be best to set `PERL5LIB` to just the custom directories if you know them at that point.

Note also that perl will ignore `PERL5LIB` if you are running under the *taint* flag.

Comment: I accepted this as an answer because it is what I was searching for. I managed to do it with something else tho. Calling the script with the `-I ` option `system ('perl -I path_to_lib script.pl')`

Comment: @asdf: Using `PERL5LIB` has the same effect as the `-I` option on the command line. What you asked for was a way to transfer the same `@INC` array to a child process, which your solution doesn't do. It was far from obvious that there was only one directory involved, and that your code knew what that directory was at the point you make the system call. It would be better if you were more careful with your questions in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly answering your question you could `do $script;` although recommended way would be to separate your common program logic into module, and `use/require` it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Storable](http://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) to save `@INC` in a file and then pick it in other script.

For example you could do something like below.

**test.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable;
store (\@INC, "test2.dump") or die "could not store";
system("perl", "test2.pl", $$) == 0 or die "error";
```

**test2.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Storable;
use Data::Dumper;
my $parentpid = shift;
my $ref = retrieve("test2.dump") or die "couldn't retrieve";
print Dumper $ref;
```

Once you get the `@INC` in `test2.pl` as `$ref`, you can modify `@INC` in `test2.pl` to take contents from `$ref`.